# expo-image-picker not returning uri on web

Tags: expo-image-picker

Trying expo-image-picker on web browser and it seems the documentation is wrong (even their example is contracdictory!)
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#usage

[image]

uri , instead of being the file path is the image in base64, any idea why ? (the prop base64 is here because I passed base64:true as parameter but it doens't change anything, uri is always base 64)